# @formatter:off in Eclipse for XML files

Tags: xml, eclipse

Is there any `@formatter:off` `@formatter:on` tag to disable autoformatting in certain parts of an XML file?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677837/formatteroff-in-eclipse-for-xml-files